# Jersey 2.x Restlets - apply governance control (like limit on number of requests allowed for restlet resource)

Tags: restlet, jersey-2.0

I have been reading the Jersey 2.17 user guide for possibities around applying governance limits on the exposed RESTLet resources. I am particularly interested in applying limits on incoming requests for a particular Jersey RESTLet resource for a particular client consumer (For example: I want to only allow 10 requests per 30 second from any particular source).

Please let me know if anybody has a feasible approach in mind based on their experience with the native API capabilities. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes this is possible, we use this in our own API's

Comment: did my answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to achieve this with Restlet is to use the [APISpark extension](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/extensions/apispark/firewall).

This similar question should answer your question:
[Limit request on a Restlet resource with APISpark restlet extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899855/limit-request-on-a-restlet-resource-with-apispark-restlet-extension)

Where you can do something like this:

```
FirewallRule rule = new PeriodicFirewallCounterRule(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new IpAddressCountingPolicy());
((PeriodicFirewallCounterRule)rule).addHandler(new RateLimitationHandler(new UniqueLimitPolicy(10)));
FirewallFilter firewallFiler = new FirewallFilter(getContext(), list(rule));
firewallFiler.setNext(router);
```

To limit the access to your app's Restlet server resources. I hope this helps or at least give you a hint.

Comment: I am not using the Restlet framework, will APISpark work with Jersey?

Comment: @javablinders You tagged your question with 'restlet' so I thought you were using Restlet framework. Anyway I suggest you try Restlet Framework than Jersey, after all Restlet has its Jersey implementation